# I cant understand an expression of type casting

Tags: c++

I got a program which has following expression but I cannot undersrand the meaning.

```
unsigned (*getid)(const char*);
```

Is this declaration of getid ? 
I am confused cause i met such expression for the first time and I couldnt come up with the keyword to search.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is that a function pointer?

Comment: It's a function pointer.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a type-cast.

`unsigned (*getid)(const char*);` declares a pointer to a function that takes a `const char*` and returns an `unsigned [int]` and calls this `getid`.

#### Further reading:

- [Function Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/function-pointers/info)

Answer (score 1):

It is a function pointer - `getid`. - with a signature demonstrated beow

e.g.

```
unsigned mygetid(const char *i) { return 0; }
getid = mygetid;
```

Answer (score 0):

`getid` is declared to be a pointer to a function which takes a `const char*` as an argument and returns an `unsigned`. Without the parentheses, the declaration would be for a function named `getid` which returns an `unsigned *` -- i.e. pointer to an unsigned integer.

For more information, see [Programs as Data: Function Pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is the declaration of a pointer to a function that returns an unsigned andtakes a char * as argument.

example:

```
// a couple of functions with the same prototypes
unsigned id_getter_1 (const char * name)
{
    // ...
}
unsigned id_getter_2 (const char * name)
{
    // ...
}

// a pointer to one of these functions
unsigned (*getid)(const char*);

// assigning the function to the pointer
if (ID_TYPE == 1)
    getid = id_getter_1;
else
    getid = id_getter_2;

// calling one of the functions through pointer
getid("xxx");
```

This is useful when you want a different code to be used depending on the circumstances. You select a variant of the code, and then use the pointer just as it it was a function name.

You might want to use typedef to make the code more readable:

```
// define a "pointer to getter function" type
typedef unsigned (* IdGetter) (const char * name);

// declare a "pointer to getter function"
IdGetter my_getter;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this declaration of getid ?

Yes it is. There is no casting here but this is a declaration of the pointer to a function that takes `const char*` as argument and returns `unsigned [int]` and this pointer is called `getid`. You can always use [this](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=unsigned+%28%2agetid%29%28const+char%2a%29%3B) site to find out meanings of such declarations.

keyword to search is: pointer to a function, declaration